# How to replace a door knob without screw

Tags: doors, doorknob

I lived in a rental apartment. Recently my roommate decide to sublease his room, so I'd like to replace my door knob with a lockable one, but I'm unable to remove this core part ( I don't know what it is called).

[image]

Can't quite find a place to screw off this thing.

[image]

Question :

1. I suspect it is installed by hammering?
2. Can this thing be uninstalled in a non-destructing way?
3. If the answer to 2 is yes, how can this be done ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's possible that the door was built around the lock, but if not then the latchbolt has to have come out the side (seen on the second image). Does the circular bezel around the latchbolt pry off?

Comment: I think when I tried to push the latchbolt from inside to outside, the bezel did pry off a tiny bit, but I'm afraid of breaking the door so I didn't  continue all they way. Should I operate on the bezel directly?

Comment: Perhaps gently, yes. (Depends on how problematic it would be to damage the door.)

Comment: Is there any recommended tool for gently prying off bezel?

Answer (score 2):

As @ Daniel Griscom suggested, I'm able to pull the latchbolt out from the side.

After prying off the bezel a little bit by a flathead screwdriver, I integrated the door knobs back and pull it side way, and successfully uninstalled the bezel and the latchbolt together.